# Application Insights API - get page view information for specific URLs

Tags: c#, .net, azure-application-insights

Does the Microsoft Application Insights have an API which I could query for information? For example, I would like to get page view count for a specific URL.

The question is very similar to this one:
[Google Analytics API - Get page view information for specific URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484009/google-analytics-api-get-page-view-information-for-specific-urls)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported yet, but is the most voted feature on user voice for Application Insights at the moment:

[Make data accessible via APIs for custom processing](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin)