# How to show page visited stats from google analytics into cordova

Tags: cordova, analytics

I have tracked my page visit stats on google analytics with javascript in cordova using [GALocalStroage](https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage) but this api does not provide api to fetch analytics so i landed up with using embed api to pull data and show in graphs from google analytics but this approch didnt worked since cookies cannot work in cordova showing below error

```
06-14 16:55:27.810 22002-22002/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(154)] "Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy", source: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.Klmf0KY_OWU.O/m=analytics/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCOscGLYYbexMh_Sw6LVOe7Uwc90QA/cb=gapi.loaded_0 (154)
```

please suggest how do show graph representing stats of google analytics into my cordova application

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484009/google-analytics-api-get-page-view-information-for-specific-urls ?

Comment: @Avijit i only only need just raw data i need to show data in some sort of graphs similar like embed api graph