# PHP - Google Analytics API - Single Page Views / Sessions

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I want to get the page views for a specific URL, lets say `123456.html`.  If I create a segment on analytics I can see that between `2018-03-01` and `2018-03-29` there were 17 sessions and 79 page views.

I've tried the following, but it's not returning any session data as far as I can tell:

```
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "XXX";
  $_date = "2018-03-01";
  $_end = "2018-03-29";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate($_date);
  $dateRange->setEndDate($_end);

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  //Create the Dimensions object.
  $pagePath = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $pagePath->setName("ga:browser");

  //Create the DimensionFilter.
  $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
  $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:pagePath');
  $dimensionFilter->setOperator('ENDS_WITH');
  $dimensionFilter->setExpressions(array('123456.html'));

  //Create the DimensionFilterClauses
  $dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause();
  $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters(array($dimensionFilter)); 

  //Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);

  //$request->setDimensions(array($pagePath));
  $request->setDimensionFilterClauses(array($dimensionFilterClause));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );

  $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );

  print_r($response);

}
```

Comment: You can check this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484009/google-analytics-api-get-page-view-information-for-specific-urls

Comment: I managed to get answer for my own let me know if you still need help?