# Display page views based on Google Analytics in Jekyll

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, jekyll, google-analytics-api, jekyll-extensions

Is there any way to display page views based on Google Analytics on a Jekyll site? We’ve been using [jekyll-ga](https://github.com/developmentseed/jekyll-ga) plugin, but it hasn’t been updated in a very long time. So updating, for example, google-api-client (to use it with the newest version of Ruby) raises a lot of errors.

It would be great to get page views from Google Analytics in real time (and not only at the time of build). But for now we are looking for any solution which can replace jekyll-ga plugin.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484009/google-analytics-api-get-page-view-information-for-specific-urls might help. You'll have to use javascript to fetch the live data after page load.

Comment: @Arcath Thank you very much! I will check it out.

Comment: @jupiteror I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @JaiSinghal Unfortunately, no. We are looking into https://pusher.com, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Please, if you're still interested in this, you can check my jekyll-ga-v2 version that implements everything in a more simple way: https://github.com/uta-org/jekyll-ga-v2