# Google Analytics - Getting page view information for a URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

(Using Reporting API V4) Whenever I am trying to get the page view information via google analytics, it doesn't seem to be filtering correctly. For example with the `setOperator("BEGINS_WITH");` and then `setExpressions("/report");` lines, what I would expect is to only retreive pages that start with mywebsitename.com/report however it gives me all sorts of stuff such as pages that start with /tag and /sponsor in addition to a bunch(but I don't think all, not actually sure about that) of the pages starting with /report.

This continues to be an issue when dealing with more specific URLs and also when using different operators. It always returns what I'm looking for but also a bunch of other random junk that seems unrelated. I also tried using just regex, but that still gave similar stuff.

I feel like my problem likely lies in not understanding exactly what all of the various objects do (in php specifically), but I have been unable to find an answer for some of that.

The closest answer I was able to find on SO here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484009/google-analytics-api-get-page-view-information-for-specific-urls) however I'm not sure what I'm doing differently than this guy. I mean one thing is that I'm not using the JSON string natively, however in the [documentation from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#metric_expressions) they use this weird function syntax Im using. Other than that it should be pretty much the same I think.

This is mostly a combination of example code from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#metric_expressions) and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php).

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
//print_r($analytics);
$response = getReport($analytics);
//print_r($response);
printResults($response);


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "HIDDEN";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("9daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

    // Create the Metrics object.
  $metricss = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $metricss->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
  $metricss->setAlias("views");

  //Create the dimensions dimension.
  $dimensions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $dimensions->setName("ga:pagePath");

  // Create the segment dimension.
  $segmentDimensions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $segmentDimensions->setName("ga:segment");

  // Create Dimension Filter.
  $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDimensionFilter();
  $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName("ga:pagePath");
  $dimensionFilter->setOperator("BEGINS_WITH");
  $dimensionFilter->setExpressions("/report");

  // Create Segment Filter Clause.
  $segmentFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilterClause();
  $segmentFilterClause->setDimensionFilter($dimensionFilter);

  // Create the Or Filters for Segment.
  $orFiltersForSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrFiltersForSegment();
  $orFiltersForSegment->setSegmentFilterClauses(array($segmentFilterClause));

  // Create the Simple Segment.
  $simpleSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SimpleSegment();
  $simpleSegment->setOrFiltersForSegment(array($orFiltersForSegment));

  // Create the Segment Filters.
  $segmentFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilter();
  $segmentFilter->setSimpleSegment($simpleSegment);

  // Create the Segment Definition.
  $segmentDefinition = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDefinition();
  $segmentDefinition->setSegmentFilters(array($segmentFilter));

  // Create the Dynamic Segment.
  $dynamicSegment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DynamicSegment();
  $dynamicSegment->setSessionSegment($segmentDefinition);
  $dynamicSegment->setName("Sessions with path");

  // Create the Segments object.
  $segment = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Segment();
  $segment->setDynamicSegment($dynamicSegment);

  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges(array($dateRange));
  $request->setDimensions(array($dimensions, $segmentDimensions));
  $request->setSegments(array($segment));
  $request->setMetrics(array($metricss));

  // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
  $getReport = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $getReport->setReportRequests(array($request));

  // Call the batchGet method.
  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );

  return $response;
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
 // print_r("reports/n");
  //print_r($reports);
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should be just returning the view count for the specific page path.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the detailed code from the examples by just using the *Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter* and the *Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause*

So an example is this

```
...

//Create the Dimensions object.
$dimension = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$dimension->setName("ga:pagePath");

// Create the DimensionFilter.
$dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:pagePath');
$dimensionFilter->setOperator('BEGINS_WITH');
$dimensionFilter->setExpressions(array('/report'));

// Create the DimensionFilterClauses
$dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause();
$dimensionFilterClause->setFilters(array($dimensionFilter));  

...

$request->setDimensions(array($dimension));
$request->setDimensionFilterClauses(array($dimensionFilterClause));
```